# ViewController Only Presented after User Touches the Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios13

I have an app in which I present a menu modally. Then, when the user selects a menu option, the menu dismisses itself and upon completion, presents another view modally according to what button the user selected.

This method worked flawlessly before, but since iOS 13 it behaves weirdly. Basically, it would not present the second view until the user touches the screen, and I cannot for the life of me find out why it behaves this way.

Here is my code (I added logs where the flow stops):

```
- (void) dismissPopUpMenu:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{        
        if ( (sender.tag == 13 ) {
            [self openPopUpWindow:sender];
        }
    }];
}

- (void) openPopUpWindow:(UIButton *)sender {
    interactionDisabledLayer.alpha              = 1.0f;

    PopUpViewController *popUpController        = [[PopUpViewController alloc] initWithPopUp:sender.tag];
    popUpController.delegate                    = self;

    NSLog(@"We get to here without problems.");

    [self presentViewController:popUpController animated:NO completion:^{
        NSLog(@"It only enters here if we touch the screen.");
        self->interactionDisabledLayer.alpha          = 0.0f;
    }];
}
```

**Update:** Delaying the code with a timer help, but I consider it a dirty hack and would like to find a better solution.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:popUpController animated:NO completion:^{
            self->interactionDisabledLayer.alpha          = 0.0f;
        }];
    });
```

Comment: I don't remember ObjC much, but sometimes this behavior happen when main thread is busy (like showing a transition) during the code execution. Hope it helps

Comment: Could be, but functions are called in completion blocks, which should take care of threading issues. Should...

Answer (score 0):

Delaying the code that presents the second UIViewController with a timer seem to help, but it is a rather dirty hack, and I would like to find a better workaround. If anyone has a proper solution, please post it as an answer and I will accept it as best.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:popUpController animated:NO completion:^{
            self->interactionDisabledLayer.alpha          = 0.0f;
        }];
    });
```